# How to sort lines of file depending on value at end of each line

Tags: c, sorting, file-io

I'm trying to create a program that takes an input file and sorts it to a new output file in ascending order depending on the number at the end of each line. For example, if the input file contains three lines below:

```
a good man 50
65
better are 7
```

The corresponding sorted output file would be three lines but sorted:

```
better are 7
a good man 50
65
```

Code I have so far:

```
int sortLines(char * inputFileName, char * outputFileName)
{
   FILE *fpin = fopen(inputFileName, "r");//open file to to read
   if (!fpin)
   {
      printf("Error in file opening\n");
      exit (-1);
   }
   FILE *fpout = fopen(outputFileName, "w");//open file to to write
   if (!fpout)
   {
      printf("Error in opfile opening\n");
      exit (-1);
   }
   char file[10][1024];
   int i = 0;
   while(fgets(file[i], sizeof(file[i]), fpin))
      i++;
   int total = i;
   for(i = 0; i<total; ++i)
      printf("%s", file[i]);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so what's your question?

Comment: @rost0031 How would I exactly do this. I don't know how to sort it properly and the put it into the output file.

Comment: @kids Can you write a `compare` function that can take two such a lines and tell which one is coming first?

Comment: @kids, Or you can store all the strings in a 2D array and then cycle through that in incrementing order and print them out based on the order of the last number.

Comment: @rost0031 Could you show me an example of that? I'm new to this. I'm needing most help on how to get the numbers separate from the string, compare and then push that to a file while still going through and comparing the sorted string to the next line.

Comment: Well, there's your first step.  Work on getting the number out of that string.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Can i get an example?

Comment: I'm new to this so I need to learn how i'm supposed to do it.

Comment: edited for what I have so far.

Comment: The simple solution is to read your lines into an array of `struct` that holds an `int` and `char*`. The lines are read into your `char *member`, then the `int` is parsed and set, then you can sort the array of struct using `qsort` with an off the shelf `compare` function for `struct.int`. Just search for **c sort array of struct** for many examples.

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/375975-sort-lines-depending-on-value-at-the-end-of-each/

Answer (score 3):

Continuing on from the comment, you can read the lines into a struct (containing the line and an int), then use `strrchr` to find the last space in each line (or if null, just take the whole line), convert the string with `strtol` or `atoi` or the like to set the `int` field of struct. Then it is a simple matter of sorting the structs based on the `int` member. I'll leave the reading into the struct to you, the sorting example is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXL 32

struct data {
    char line[MAXL];
    int n;
};

int compare_n (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    struct data *ia = (struct data *)a;
    struct data *ib = (struct data *)b;
    return (int)(ia->n - ib->n);
}

int main (void)
{
    struct data lines[] = {{"a good man 50", 50}, {"65", 65}, {"better are 7", 7}};
    size_t nstr = sizeof lines / sizeof *lines;
    size_t i = 0;

    qsort (lines, nstr, sizeof *lines, compare_n);

    for (i = 0; i < nstr; i++)
        printf (" %s\n", lines[i].line);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/struct_sort_int
 better are 7
 a good man 50
 65
```

---

### full example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXL 64

/* simple struct holding char array and int */
struct data {
    char line[MAXL];
    int n;
};

/* qsort comparison function for int 'n' */
int compare_n (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    struct data *ia = (struct data *)a;
    struct data *ib = (struct data *)b;
    return (int)(ia->n - ib->n);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2 ) {    /* validate at least 1 argument provided */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input, usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    struct data lines[MAXL] = {{{0}, 0}};   /* array of struct      */
    char *ln = NULL;    /* buffer for getline, getline allocates    */
    size_t n = 0;       /* initial size of buf, 0 getline decides   */
    ssize_t nchr = 0;   /* getline return, no. of chars read        */
    size_t idx = 0;     /* index for array of struct                */
    size_t i = 0;       /* general iteration variable               */
    FILE *fp = NULL;    /* file pointer for input file              */

    if (!(fp = fopen (argv[1], "r"))) {     /* validate file open   */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed. '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each line in file */
    while ((nchr = getline (&ln, &n, fp)) != -1)
    {
        while (nchr > 0 && (ln[nchr-1] == '\n' || ln[nchr-1] == '\r'))
            ln[--nchr] = 0;     /* strip newline or carriage rtn    */

        if (!nchr) continue;            /* skip blank lines         */

        if (nchr > MAXL - 1) {          /* test for line > MAXL -1  */
            fprintf (stderr, 
                    "warning: line will exceeded %d chars.\n", MAXL);
            continue;                   /* number at end invalid    */
        }

        strcpy (lines[idx].line, ln);  /* copy to struct.line       */

        char *p = NULL;
        if (!(p = strrchr (ln, ' ')))   /* pointer to last space    */
            p = ln;                     /* if no space, then line   */

        lines[idx].n = atoi (p);        /* convert string to int    */

        idx++;                          /* increment index          */

        if (idx == MAXL) {              /* if MAXL read, break      */
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: %d lines read.\n", MAXL);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (fp) fclose (fp);                /* close input file         */
    if (ln) free (ln);                  /* free line buffer mem     */

    qsort (lines, idx, sizeof *lines, compare_n);   /* sort struct  */

    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)           /* print sorted array       */
        printf (" %s\n", lines[i].line);

    return 0;
}
```

Take a look and let me know if you have questions. Your data was in the file `dat/endno.txt` for my test. I'll add comments when I get a chance.

**note:** updated to skip blank lines and to check line length against `MAXL` to eliminate the possibility of a write beyond end of lines and skip lines that would be truncated rendering the number at end invalid.

---

### without `struct` statically allocated arrays

The following is an example that uses two 2D arrays, one for the `lines` and then one holding the original line index and number at end of line. Unlike the dynamically allocated example below, this example is limited to reading `MAXL` lines from the file or no more than `MAXS` characters each. If a line is exactly `MAXS` characters long (including the null-terminator), it must be discarded, because there is no way of knowing if the number at end remains valid. The 2D array containing the line index and number at end is sorted based on the number at end, then lines are printed based on the original line index resulting in the lines printing in sorted order by number at end. While this may look simpler, it is far more limited than the method utilizing the `struct` or the dynamically allocated approach below. This is about all I can think to do to get your going. Good luck. Drop a line if you have questions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXL 64
#define MAXS 128

int cmpint (const void *a, const void *b);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2 ) {    /* validate at least 1 argument provided */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input, usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    int numidx[MAXL][2] = {{0}};    /* array of integers                        */
    char lines[MAXL][MAXS] = {{0}}; /* array of strings                         */
    char ln[MAXS] = {0};            /* buffer for fgets, MAXS in length         */
    ssize_t nchr = 0;               /* getline return, no. of chars read        */
    size_t idx = 0;                 /* index for array of struct                */
    size_t i = 0;                   /* general iteration variable               */
    FILE *fp = NULL;                /* file pointer for input file              */

    if (!(fp = fopen (argv[1], "r"))) {         /* validate file open   */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed. '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each line in file */
    while (fgets (ln, MAXS, fp) != NULL)
    {
        nchr = strlen (ln);             /* get length of ln         */

        while (nchr > 0 && (ln[nchr-1] == '\n' || ln[nchr-1] == '\r'))
            ln[--nchr] = 0;     /* strip newline or carriage rtn    */

        if (!nchr || nchr == MAXS - 2)  /* skip blank lines + full  */
            continue;                   /* lines (end no. invalid)  */

        strcpy (lines[idx], ln);        /* copy ln to lines[idx]    */

        char *p = NULL;
        if (!(p = strrchr (ln, ' ')))   /* pointer to last space    */
            p = ln;                     /* if no space, then line   */

        numidx[idx][0] = atoi (p);      /* save end no. in array    */
        numidx[idx][1] = idx;           /* save line index in array */

        idx++;                          /* increment index          */

        if (idx == MAXL) {              /* if MAXL read, break      */
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: %d lines read.\n", MAXL);
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose (fp);

    qsort (numidx, idx, sizeof (int) * 2, cmpint);/* sort array     */

    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)           /* print sorted array       */
        printf (" %s\n", lines[numidx[i][1]]);

    return 0;
}

/* qsort integer compare function */
int cmpint (const void *pa, const void *pb )
{
    const int *a = pa;
    const int *b = pb;
    if (a[0] < b[0]) 
        return -1;
    return (b[0] < a[0]);
}
```

---

### without `struct`, dynamically allocated arrays

To get around using a structure to hold the string an number, you can use 2 arrays. One to hold the strings, and another 2D array holding the original line index and number at end of line (2 integers). You then `qsort` the integer array on the (number at end) element, then loop through each line printing out the lines in sorted order based on the line index value of the sorted array. This is set to handle lines of any length and reallocate the number of lines (in each array) as needed. Since the dynamic allocation may be a bit much, I'm working on a static array version as well, but it will be tomorrow before I have time. Here is the first version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXL 64

int cmpint (const void *a, const void *b);
char **realloc_char (char **sp, size_t *n);
int **realloc_int (int **ip, size_t *n);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2 ) {    /* validate at least 1 argument provided */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input, usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    int **numidx = NULL;    /* array of pointers-to-pointer-to-int      */
    char **lines = NULL;    /* array of pointer-to-pointer-to-char      */
    char *ln = NULL;        /* buffer for getline, getline allocates    */
    size_t n = 0;           /* initial size of buf, 0 getline decides   */
    ssize_t nchr = 0;       /* getline return, no. of chars read        */
    size_t idx = 0;         /* index for array of struct                */
    size_t i = 0;           /* general iteration variable               */
    size_t maxl = MAXL;     /* holds current allocation size of arrays  */
    FILE *fp = NULL;        /* file pointer for input file              */

    if (!(fp = fopen (argv[1], "r"))) {         /* validate file open   */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed. '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* allocate MAXL pointers to int* */
    if (!(numidx = calloc (MAXL, sizeof *numidx))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: memory allocation failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* allocate MAXL pointers to char* */
    if (!(lines = calloc (MAXL, sizeof *lines))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: memory allocation failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each line in file */
    while ((nchr = getline (&ln, &n, fp)) != -1)
    {
        while (nchr > 0 && (ln[nchr-1] == '\n' || ln[nchr-1] == '\r'))
            ln[--nchr] = 0;     /* strip newline or carriage rtn    */

        if (!nchr) continue;            /* skip blank lines         */

        lines[idx] = strdup (ln);       /* copy ln to lines[idx]    */

        /* allocate space for 2 int at numidx[idx] */
        if (!(numidx[idx] = calloc (2, sizeof **numidx))) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: memory allocation failed.\n");
            return 1;
        }

        char *p = NULL;
        if (!(p = strrchr (ln, ' ')))   /* pointer to last space    */
            p = ln;                     /* if no space, then line   */

        numidx[idx][0] = atoi (p);      /* save end no. in array    */
        numidx[idx][1] = idx;           /* save line index in array */

        idx++;                          /* increment index          */

        if (idx == maxl) {              /* if idx = maxl reallocate */
            size_t tsz = maxl;          /* tmp var, each get maxl   */
            numidx = realloc_int (numidx, &tsz);
            lines = realloc_char (lines, &maxl);
        }
    }

    if (ln) free (ln);
    fclose (fp);

    qsort (numidx, idx, sizeof *numidx, cmpint);  /* sort struct  */

    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)           /* print sorted array       */
        printf (" %s\n", lines[numidx[i][1]]);

    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++) {         /* free allocated memory    */
        free (numidx[i]);
        free (lines[i]);
    }
    free (numidx);
    free (lines);

    return 0;
}

/* qsort integer compare function */
int cmpint (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const int **ia = (const int **)a;
    const int **ib = (const int **)b;
    return (*ia)[0] - (*ib)[0];
}

/** realloc an array of pointers to strings setting memory to 0.
*  reallocate an array of character arrays setting
*  newly allocated memory to 0 to allow iteration
*/
char **realloc_char (char **sp, size_t *n)
{
    char **tmp = realloc (sp, 2 * *n * sizeof *sp);
    if (!tmp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error: struct reallocation failure.\n");
        // return NULL;
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    sp = tmp;
    memset (sp + *n, 0, *n * sizeof *sp); /* memset new ptrs 0 */
    *n *= 2;

    return sp;
}

/** realloc an array of pointers to int* setting memory to 0.
*  reallocate an array of integer arrays setting
*  newly allocated memory to 0 to allow iteration
*/
int **realloc_int (int **ip, size_t *n)
{
    int **tmp = realloc (ip, 2 * *n * sizeof *ip * 4);
    if (!tmp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error: struct reallocation failure.\n");
        // return NULL;
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ip = tmp;
    memset (ip + *n, 0, *n * sizeof *ip * 4); /* memset new ptrs 0 */
    *n *= 2;

    return ip;
}
```

Comment: How would I do it from an input file?

Comment: Alright, give me a bit and I'll post a complete example starting with the read from the data file.

Comment: @kids comments added to code, let me know if you have questions. Just because it is basic, doesn't mean it's easy or that you should just be able to look at it and understand it. There is a lot going on in that short bit of code. That's why they make excellent assignments `:p`

Comment: `strcpy (lines[idx].line, ln);` There is a possibility to cause an overflow.

Comment: `strncpy (lines[idx].line, ln, nchr+1);` fixed to prevent possibility of overflow.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, normal `strncpy` limit wouldn't work with logic of program, adjusted to insure length tested before `strcpy`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin My issue with this is that I am trying to achieve the solution in one simple method. My entire program is here : http://pastie.org/10191206#7

Comment: @kids I'll take a look at let you know. The struct approach is about as simple a solution as is correctly possible. The issue is **How to coordinate the numeric sort while maintaining the correct relationship with each character string?** You have to extract the number from the end of each line, then sort and have the lines reflect the sort order. You can either use the sting tools (e.g. `strrchr` to isolate the number at the end, or simply use pointer arithmetic) Using the string functions is by far the shortest. I'll look and report back. `exit (-1)` (-1 not allowed)

Comment: @kids I see you are thinking you can read the input, write a temp file `out1` with the number and text manipulated in some way, then read  `out1` and write the final sorted lines to `out2`.  It is currently much longer than the approach using `struct` and that is with 50% of the required logic missing. Say you do read the file, save the original line index and the number, then you would sort based on the number and  write the **line index** out to your temp file (or just save an array of sorted indexes). You then must read the file again into an array, and write based on the sorted indexes.

Comment: @kids it is doable, but you run into the same problem **How do I coordinate the original line index with the line end number through the sort?** Which will pretty much take you back to a struct solution. You can try it, but you will pull your hair out trying to coordinate indexes between `pre-sort` and `post-sort` and find you have code **5X** longer than using a struct. **Do you have a requirement saying you cannot use a `struct`?**

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I've been trying to figure a way of doing that. I knew I needed to try to put it to a char array. Here's my updated method: http://pastie.org/10191264 Im fairly new at all of this so all this help is incredibly appreciated! So from here, is it possible to sort by the numbers? Or how else would I do that? 2D array?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I was told that I cannot us strtol() method.

Comment: @kids, I'll take a look and work on an alternate solution after I get my kids (no pun intended) dropped off at the movies. It's doable, but it is just taking the long way around `:p`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I think the instructor wants us to only do it in one single method instead of breaking it up in multiple.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Okay, awesome! I appreciate this soo much! You have no idea! :)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I got clarification & I can include more methods to help the sort method. Except I cannot use strtol()

Comment: I've got a couple almost done. The first one dynamically allocates everything. I'm working on a simpler static example. I'll post the dynamic allocation/reallocation method, and post the other tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the entire file into a single buffer, create an array of structures containing pointers to lines and the values at the end of each line (scan for newline characters), then sort the array of structures by the values, and output the data according to the pointers in the sorted array of structures.

Comment: Use memchr() (or wmemchr() for unicode) to search for newline '\n' (or 0xa). It returns a pointer to the newline. So that pointer + 1 is the start of a line. After reading the file, check if the last character read is a newline and if not, append a newline after the last character.